# public void requestLayout()

Tags: android, layout

I was looking at this method `public void requestLayout ()` in the android docs, I notice the sentence below that is highlighted, but I don't understand what the word `layout pass` mean in that sentence, I know this is not an English forum, but it is kind of related to android, so please can someone explain this to me? I wouldn't have asked if I were an English native speaker, and google didn't have any answer at all. Thank you very much.

public void requestLayout ()

Call this when something has changed which has invalidated the layout of this view. `This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree. This should not be called while the view hierarchy is currently in a layout pass (isInLayout()`. If layout is happening, the request may be honored at the end of the current layout pass (and then layout will run again) or after the current frame is drawn and the next layout occurs.

Subclasses which override this method should call the superclass method to handle possible request-during-layout errors correctly.

Comment: Android makes "passes" over the layout in order to collect, measure, draw, etc. the contents of the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout pass describes the order in which Android draws the views. Please read: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

So the OS will first draw the root(parent) layout and then proceed to draw the children. When you do requestLayout, it redraws the Views in that order.